# Bootstrapped linear regression with unbalanced factors

Tags: regression, categorical-data, bootstrap, unbalanced-classes

I am investigating the relationship between `Valence ratings` (continuous response variable) and `Condition` (4-level factor) as well as `Culture` (factor).
Note that I am more familiar with conducting linear regressions rather than ANOVA in R, so I am using regressions ( lm() ) but that shouldn't matter. I am using BCa bootstrapping to  overcome the unreliability of standard errors and significance values due to non-normality and, most importantly, heteroskedasticity present in my data.
My question is: how much of a problem is unequal sample size for linear regressions?
I am wondering which culture groups I can include in my analyses, given that the number of observations per culture group in each condition are very unequal, see table

`xtabs(~Culture + Condition, data = dweiqu)
                Condition
Culture          VisualVocalVerbal Visual Vocal VocalVerbal
  Confucian                    217    198   188          82
  Southern Asia                  4      4     4           8
  Latin America                  0      5     1           2
  Nordic                         3      2     2           5
  Anglo                         42     38    36          43
  Germanic                      19     17    18          11
  Latin Europe                  45     27    35          34
  African                        0      1     2           0
  Eastern Europe                 8     12    17          15
  Middle Eastern                 0      0     0           0
  Mixed                          0      0     0           0`

I am thinking of including any category of `Culture` for which no less than 20 observations are present per condition, but I don't have a solid rationale for this, and don't even know if it is valid. Any thought?

I have looked for articles and other posts on this forum about unequal samples in ANOVA's, but the concerns mostly seem to relate to heteroskedasticity & unequal sample size. Since I apply BCa bootstrapping, I assume that I could not be too concerned about heteroskedasticity in my case...?

Comment: Why is homoskedasticity a problem you are trying to overcome?

Comment: @StatsStudent Oh sorry, I meant heteroskedasticity! I'll edit this now